# One-way relations in QLIK Sense

Tags: qliksense

I have some graph-tree data structure, it seems to organization chart with fixed levels.
We need have application to annalise this structure. And one of these task is find all chains of units managed by  person from list. For example there are such structure

Unit A1 (Person X1)
--Unit A11 (Person X11)
---Unit A111 (Person X111)
---Unit A112 (Person X112)
--Unit A12 (Person X12)
---Unit A121 (Person X121)
Unit B1 (Person Y1)
--Unit B11 (Person Y11)
--Unit B12 (Person Y12)
---Unit B121 (Person Y121)
---Unit B122 (Person Y122)

When I have list of person Person X111, Person X121, Person Y11 I want to filter this structure and get

```
Unit A1 (Person X1)-Unit A11 (Person X11)-Unit A111 (Person X111)
Unit A1 (Person X1)-Unit A12 (Person X12)-Unit A121 (Person X121)
Unit B1 (Person Y1)-Unit B11 (Person Y11)
```

I try to make tables for each layer, where are Parent Unit ID and Person ID, and table with Persons where are Person ID and Person Name.
But in this case QLIK understand it as loop.

If there are some way to make one-way relations to filter Units by Person, but not filter Persons by Units?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the [`HierarchyBelongsTo` prefix](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/HierarchyBelongsTo.htm) in the Data Load Editor to structure your data in a way that allows Qlik to correctly treat it as tree-like data.

Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
[data]:
load *
  , AutoNumber([ParentUnit]) as [ParentUnitID]
  , AutoNumber([Unit]) as [UnitID]
;
load * inline [
ParentUnit      ,   Unit        ,   Person
Unit A11        ,   Unit A111   ,   Person X111
Unit A11        ,   Unit A112   ,   Person X112
Unit A12        ,   Unit A121   ,   Person X121
Unit A1         ,   Unit A11    ,   Person X11
Unit A1         ,   Unit A12    ,   Person X12
                ,   Unit A1     ,   Person X1
Unit B12        ,   Unit B121   ,   Person Y121                
Unit B12        ,   Unit B122   ,   Person Y122
Unit B1         ,   Unit B11    ,   Person Y11
Unit B1         ,   Unit B12    ,   Person Y12
                ,   Unit B1     ,   Person Y1
];


[hierarchy]:
HierarchyBelongsTo (UnitID, ParentUnitID, Unit, AncestorID, AncestorName, DepthDiff)
LOAD
    [UnitID]
  , [ParentUnitID]
  , [Unit]
resident [data];

Drop Field [Unit] From [hierarchy];
```

The `[data]` table is just your example tree-like data reformatted for this exercise. The `[ParentUnit]` column is the unit above `[Unit]`, and then `[Person]` is just the person that goes with `[Unit]`. Using a preceding load, we also use the `AutoNumber()` function to create a unique ID field for both the `[ParentUnit]` column and the `[Unit]` column.

The `[hierarchy]` table uses the `HierarchyBelongsTo` prefix to properly load the tree-like data. Here are the parameters we're using here:

- UnitID - This is our node ID.
- ParentUnitID - This is our parent ID.
- Unit - This is the node name.
- AncestorID - Just using the example field name from the Qlik Help page.
- AncestorName - Just using the example field name from the Qlik Help page.
- DepthDiff - Just using the example field name from the Qlik Help page.

We then drop the `[Unit]` field from our new `[hierarchy]` table to avoid an unnecessary synthetic key.

Once this loads, we get a data model like this:

[image: Screenshot of a Qlik Sense data model]

And we can explore this structure like so:

[Link to GIF of Qlik Sense dashboard](https://s3.arcanalytics.us/s3/public-assets/Arc%20Analytics%20-%20SO%20upload%20-%20Hierarchies%201.gif) (Note that this GIF is ~20mb so I'm hosting it on my company site)

Check out [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/handling-hierarchical-data.htm?) to read more about how to handle hierarchical data.